# Upgrade to Nginx 1.11 from 1.6?

Tags: nginx

Faced very strange thing upgrading nginx 1.6 -> 1.11 on Debian 8 jessie. All my /etc/nginx/site-enabled configurations were simply ignored when starting nginx. I have all includes in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and all my paths are just fine. Reason wanted to do this - http2 support, but eventually went back to 1.6.

Anyone saw similar and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess when you have upgrade the installer overwrite the nginx.conf file.
Check in your nginx file if you have:

```
include /etc/nginx/site-enabled/*.conf;
```

Check on the docs for more details:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include

Comment: This one is there as well as includes for site-enabled/*